# How do I solve text too wide error in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

The text is too long and will random break my first word over the entire first line...I don't know how to make it look like the other with short text. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{simplecv}
\begin{document}
\vspace{1em}
\entrybig
{\textbf{LexBox}}{Nov 2020 - Present}
LexBox represents the fastest and the most efficient way to make a contravention complaint without to get in touch with a lawyer.
\\\textbf{Technologies:} C\#, ASP.NET, jQuery AJAX, CSS \& HTML
\entrybig
{\textbf{GAM - Group Activity Manager}}{Oct 2020 - Present}
{This application is designed to remote control multiple desktops at the same time. \\
\textbf{Technologies:} C\#, .NET Framework}
\end{document}
```

and the .sty file is [this](https://gofile.io/d/052rbF)

and the result is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upAhB.jpg)

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Sorry, now I think it's ok

Comment: Does not compile for me

Comment: Now it's ok xD I forgot about the .sty file

Comment: nope. missing packages...

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/read/pcbbydryxzcs take it =))))))) idk, what is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three major problems:

- you must not use `\entrybig` on its own, it needs to be inside a list, e.g. `\outerlist{}`
- The syntax you use for `\entrybig` is wrong. This macro takes 4 mandatory arguments, not 2, not 3, exactly 4
- as this macro gets inserted into table cells, you must not abuse `\\` for line breaks

---

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

% Choose bibliography style for formatting list of publications
\usepackage[style=ieee,url=false,doi=false,maxbibnames=99,sorting=ydnt,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{papers}

% Choose theme, e.g. black, RedViolet, ForestGreen, MidnightBlue
\def\theme{MidnightBlue}

\usepackage{simplecv}

\begin{document}


See more of my projects on \website{https://github.com/Mihutzen}
\vspace{1em}

\outerlist{

\entrybig
{\textbf{ETH Zurich}}
{Zurich, CH}
{M.S. in Computer Science, GPA: 5.63/6.00}
{2018\textendash 2020}

}
\end{document}
```

[image]